# NuGet Not Adding Include Directories

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package-restore

I am developing an application with VS Professional 2013 that uses a NuGet package called SFML.  I am now trying out the Express edition of VS 2015, and I wanted to test it by building this application.  The app's source code is on GitHub, and I can clone the repository into a new local directory and open it in VS 2015 just fine.  When I build, the NuGet packages are restored and the "packages" folder is added to the local solution folder.  However, the C++ code itself fails to build,  throwing the compiler error:

> Error (active) cannot open source file "SFML\System\NonCopyable.hpp"

at a line that reads

```
#include <SFML\System\NonCopyable.hpp>
```

This error never occurred in VS 2013, which I assumed was because NuGet added the appropriate paths to the project's Additional Include Directories.  Is that not happening now because of a NuGet issue or a VS 2015 issue, or just because I'm missing something?  Is there any way that I can resolve this issue using my current 2015 Express edition?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. In my example I noticed my NugGet package had v120 in the name **Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Cpp.v120.WinDesktop** I was getting error unable to find include file **pplx\pplxtasks.h**

To fix this issue:

1. Right click your **Project** in Solution Explorer and select **Properties**
2. In Configuration Properties - General change **Platform Toolset** to the version matching your NuGet package - in this case **Visual Studio 2013 (v120)**

More detail on changing platform toolset here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ff770576.aspx

Now the project compiles correctly.

Comment: thanks for the reply!  I'm not sure I follow your solution though.  What is "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Cpp.v120.WinDesktop"?  Is that a file, a setting?  Also I cannot find "Platform Toolset" anywhere in the solution Configuration Properties.  I see a "Platform" column, but its only allowed values are Win32 and x64, nothing about Visual Studio 2013 (v120).  In addition, I've noticed that the Header Files and Source Files filter inside my solution's projects are all empty, even though the .vcxproj files show the correct ItemGroup elements.  Any idea what that's about?  Thanks again.

Comment: It is in Project properties, not Solution properties.

Comment: In my case Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Cpp.v120.WinDesktop was the name of the Nuget package, which gave me the clue to the solution. This may be different for your solution; I just put the name here if someone else has problem with this same NuGet package.

Comment: The file you have a problem with is part of the NuGet Boost Package, if you right click the Project, Manage NuGet Packages, make sure boost is installed.